# Display multiple pages in a single PDF document using zend_pdf

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, zend-pdf

How can we display text or images on multiple pages using zend_Pdf component?

Comment: ... by creating a multi-page PDF?

Comment: Exactly but what code should I write?

Comment: Could you please provide some more details?

Comment: Actually I have to Generate Pdf of product's image in magento. Any how I am able to generate Pdf of product's images.Now the problem is  that when I open PDF document there is only one product's image ie it contains last product's image out of all product collections. I think the reason might be that the iteration code for creating next page for other product might not be working. Could you please help me in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `display text or images on multiple pages`, but your script is loaded in a single page, you may `include()` other pages to this page and may create a PDF.

Comment: Can you provide me chunk of code for it